# How to hide Controllers routes in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi project and I got myself in this situation. Let's say that I have a Route :

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/GG")]
public class StorkUserController : ApiController
{
    private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    [Route("UpdateUser")]
    [HttpPost]
```

So When I start the application, if i directly type in my browser this route :

```
http://localhost:52494/api/
```

I will get this Error with some details :

[image]

Or if I navigate to `http://localhost:52494/api/v1/GG` I get :

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52494/api/v1/GG/'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'v1'."}
```

How to prevent for this Happen since these routes could be easily to be found, and instead of it, show something like "ERROR 404"! Thanks!

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq9PNfcwnvI&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=35)  it might help you  :)